# Character doesn't jump in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I've been working on character movement and I created a method to make the character jump when the up key is pressed but there is no response in the character's movement.
Can anyone see what is wrong? Here is my code:

Constructor

```cs
public PlayerSprite(string name, string magicTextureName,Vector2 position, Vector2 velocity, AnimatedTextureData textureData, SpritePresentationInfo spritePresentationInfo,SpritePositionInfo spritePositionInfo, Keys leftKey, Keys rightKey, int frameRate, int startFrame, bool bRepeatAnimation)
  : base(name, textureData, spritePresentationInfo, spritePositionInfo, frameRate, startFrame, bRepeatAnimation)
```

Takes in position and velocity.

This is in the update.

```cs
if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isFirstKeyPress(Keys.Up))
{
    bPause = false;
    updateJump();
}
```

updateJump function

```cs
 public void updateJump()
 {
     jumpPosition += jumpVelocity;
     if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
         jumpVelocity.X = 3f;
     else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
         jumpVelocity.X = -3f;
     else
         jumpVelocity.X = 0f;

     if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
     {
         jumpPosition.Y -= 10f;
         jumpVelocity.Y -= 5f;
         hasJumped = true;
     }
     if (hasJumped == true)
     {
         float i = 1;
         jumpVelocity.Y += 0.15f * i;
     }
     if (jumpPosition.Y + animatedTextureData.Height() >= 450)
     {
         hasJumped = false;
     }
     if (hasJumped == false)
     {
         jumpVelocity.Y = 0f;
     }
 }
```

Where I call this in main

```cs
 AnimatedTextureData playerAnimatedTextureData = (AnimatedTextureData)textureManager.Get("PlayerAnimation");
 SpritePresentationInfo playerAnimatedPresentationInfo = new SpritePresentationInfo(playerAnimatedTextureData.FULLSOURCERECTANGLE, 1);
 SpritePositionInfo playerAnimatedPositionInfo = new SpritePositionInfo(new Vector2(100, 700), playerAnimatedTextureData.Width(), playerAnimatedTextureData.Height(), 0, 2, playerAnimatedTextureData.CENTREORIGIN);

 this.playerSprite = new PlayerSprite("PlayerAnimation", "FireballAnimation", new Vector2(50, 50), new Vector2(50, 50), playerAnimatedTextureData, playerAnimatedPresentationInfo, playerAnimatedPositionInfo,Keys.Left, Keys.Right, 10, 0, true);
 spriteManager.Add(playerSprite);
```

Comment: You should debug your code with a breakpoint and see what's wrong, if it runs correctly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have `float i = 1; jumpVelocity.Y += 0.15f * i;` instead of just `jumpVelocity.Y += 0.15f`?

Comment: Aw i took the code out of a book i thought that was pretty  bad coding myself but i assumed it was going to do something with i at a later stage obviously not.

Answer (score 3):

My guess:
I don't know what this function is programmed to do, but if it only detects the pressing down of the Up key, then the Jump is no longer updated after the first frame.

```
if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isFirstKeyPress(Keys.Up))
{
    bPause = false;
    updateJump();
}
```

Once you correct this and the updateJump() function is called every Update cycle, then the fireball should escape the screen pretty quickly as long as you hold the Up key.

Comment: I changed it to isKeyDown and im not gettin any joy the function is supposed to make the character jump so much up the screen and then let him come back down with a sense of gravity...

Comment: try to simply put "updateJump();" on its own in your Update() method, do not you your SpriteManager class at all for this.